# Searching for TableCurve like, prebuilt list of functions and tools, to add to Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm searching for tablecurve functionalities on Mathematica.

I like a lot the functionalities of tablecurve 2d and 3d. When looking for a function that doesn’t need any sort of "physical" justification to a given set of data, having thousands of predefined functions and an adjustment function that takes just a couple of seconds (literally) is very handy.

http://www.sigmaplot.com/products/tablecurve2d/tablecurve2d.php
(There’s a trial, if you want to try it)

Does someone ever heard of any attempt to do the same in Mathematica? If I'm not mistaken, M8 has a lot of functionalities that would make this kind of program approach easy to establish (thought I'm not a specialist in this area). And once the basic functionality was set, one would just add more functions to a list, and then the adjustment of a data set to all the functions on that list would be launched, managed, sorted, etc, by the main package.

Can someone help me?
    Point an already existing package, or
    Give a small code to launch an adjustment on a set of functions, or
    Etc
Thank you,
P Fonseca

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking for simultaneous calls to `FindFit` with a preset choice of models, forgoing any fit diagnostics ?

Comment: Mathematica has a broad range of fit capabilities, with Fit, FindFit, LinearModelFit, NonLInearModelfit etc. Fitting to a whole set of functions should be doable, but I don't think mindless fitting data to unknown models (what tablecurve seems to do) is good science.

Comment: In a lot of cases, I'm not looking for good science. Let's suppose I've taken out a set of data points that I completely don't know it's "scientific" model. I can use an interpolation function model to use that data in a continuous function. Nevertheless, as you can imagine, a well defined function can be much more useful than the interpolation model (ex.: transfer it easily to another program).

Comment: About 2 yrs ago, I personally asked that same question to Stephen Wolfram. I don't remember his exact answer, but I remember that it was something that they were looking into.

Comment: @Sjoerd this is not a refutation, but sometimes a good apparent fit is better than "good science."  Consider the application of gap-filling or extending images via extrapolation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Agree, this will have sensible purposes (as the OP already stated two comments above), but there are lots of disciplines where they consider data fitting the same as building a model. IMHO, it doesn't do anything in that sense. It doesn't usually give you any understanding of the underlying mechanism, it just offers you the opportunity to describe your data more or less succinctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic recipe might be something along the following lines:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, data]
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

functions =
  {
   {Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}},
   {Sin[a x], {a}},
   {1 + a x + b x^2 + c x^3, {a, b, c}}
  };

Sort[
 Table[
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, functions[[i, 1]], functions[[i, 2]],x];
  {nlm["AdjustedRSquared"], nlm["BestFit"]},
  {i, Length[functions]}
  ], #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &
 ]

==> {{0.974277, 1 - 0.996311 x + 0.541669 x^2 - 0.0461196 x^3}, 
     {0.93636, Log[1.50632 + 1.42633 x^2]}, {-0.0304978, Sin[1.23596 x]}}
```

Comment: Great. I will just add: output = (your Sort[Table[...]])
and then
 Manipulate[ Column[{output[[nb, 2]], output[[nb, 1]], Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full], Plot[output[[nb, 2]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}], ImageSize -> 400]}, ItemSize -> {Automatic, {3, 3, 20}}], {nb, 1, Length[output], 1}]